# Delete all files in a directory that do not have a file extension

Tags: python, windows, file-extension

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
import os

def memeFilter():
    images = [".jpeg",".png",".jpg",".gif"]
    
    for file in os.listdir("memes"):
        for ex in images:
            if file != file.endswith(ex):
                os.remove("memes/" + file)
```

But every time I run it I get this error:

```
Starting Proccess...
Downloading memes from subreddit...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LoneWanderer\Desktop\YT shorts bot\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    memeFilter()
  File "c:\Users\LoneWanderer\Desktop\YT shorts bot\program_assets\memeFilter.py", line 9, in memeFilter
    os.remove("memes/" + file)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'memes/14gp7gmt8loa1.jpg'
```

Comment: `file` contains a string, `endswith` method returns a boolean value. These can never be equal.

Comment: What does this error tell you?

Comment: @СергейКох OP provided the error in the question...

Comment: @MatthewTitus Does my answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `for ex in images` loop checks if the file doesn't contain the extension four times, so if it doesn't match any then it will try to delete it four times.

Also, although it isn't causing an error, it's generally better to use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join paths rather than string concatenation.

Using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression instead worked for me:

```
import os


def memeFilter():
    exts = [".jpeg", ".png", ".jpg", ".gif"]
    
    for file in os.listdir("memes"):
        if not any(file.endswith(ex) for ex in exts):
            os.remove(os.path.join("memes", file))


memeFilter()
```